# Stop React Axios Polling after 5 errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, polling

I have implemented a polling mechanism in my react app for the notification.
So every 2 seconds I am sending a request to my api (in another domain) and checking, whether there are new notifications.

Sometimes is my Api is down. My applications keeps on sending the request every 2 seconds. Now I want to implement that after 5 errors - there should be a break for e.g 10 minutes. The problem is that when my api is down I receive many errors in the browser console (see attachment [image: ErrorCount in Console])

Here is how I've implemented the polling.

withPolling.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

export const withPolling = (pollingAction, duration = 2000) => Component => {
  const Wrapper = () =>
    class extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.pollingAction();
        this.dataPolling = setInterval(() => {
          this.props.pollingAction();
        }, duration);
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.dataPolling);
      }
      render() {
        return <Component {...this.props} />;
      }
    };
  const mapStateToProps = () => ({});
  const mapDispatchToProps = { pollingAction };
  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Wrapper());
};
```

My Component, which will be setted into my Navbar, that sends the polling when User is authenticated
NotificationsButtonNavbarWithPolling.jsx

```
import { loadNotifications } from "../../redux/actions/notificationAction";
import { withPolling } from "../../Utilities/withPolling";

class NotificationsButtonNavbarWithPolling extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let headroom = new Headroom(document.getElementById("navbar-main"));
    // initialise
    headroom.init();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <UncontrolledDropdown navbar-nav left>
        <DropdownToggle nav style={{ color: "#ffffff" }}>
          <i className="fa fa-bell nav-link-inner--text" />
        </DropdownToggle>

        <DropdownMenu right className="navbar-light">
          {this.props.notifications ? (
            <>
              {Object.entries(this.props.notifications).map(([key, value]) => (
                <DropdownItem key={key}>{value}</DropdownItem>
              ))}
              )}
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Row>
                <Row>
                  <div>Notifications</div>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <div>There are no notifications yet.</div>
                </Row>
              </Row>
            </>
          )}
          <DropdownItem divider />
          <DropdownItem>
            <Button
              className="nav-link-inner--text ml-2"
              href="/allNotifications"
            >
              Show all Notifications
            </Button>
          </DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </UncontrolledDropdown>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  notifications: state.notifications
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export default withPolling(loadNotifications)(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(NotificationsButtonNavbarWithPolling)
);
```

The request will be sended with axios - nothing spectacular.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [axios-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-retry) library. I think it will suit your needs well.

Comment: @IAmVisco thank you very much. I saw axios-retry already. But since the polling is comming by the withPolling.js file - I'm not sure, where I could implement the axios-retry. What do you think - where should I place it best?

Comment: I think it belongs close to the axios instance - so inside that `pollingAction` function you are passing.